# validate list of lists with a unique and common element

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a list where each element with 2 integer list. I need to validate this list and it will be valid if only one element is repeated in all the lists and the rest all should be unique

```
my_list = [ [1, 2]] # valid
my_list = [ [1, 2], [3, 1], [1, 4], [1, 9]]  # valid, element 1 present in all 3 list and 2,3,4,9 are unique.
my_list = [ [8, 2], [3, 8], [5, 4]]  # invalid, 8 not present in third list
my_list = [ [6, 2], [3, 6], [6, 2]]  # invalid, 2 repeated
```

I tried with the below code and it seems to be working. Can there be a better and easy solution

```
def validate(my_list):

    if len(my_list) == 0:
        return False
    if len(my_list) == 1:
        if my_list[0][0] == my_list[0][1]: return False
        else: return True
    intersection_set = set(my_list[0]).intersection(set(my_list[1]))
    for li in my_list[2:]:
        if li[0] == li[1]:
            return False
        intersection_set =  intersection_set.intersection(set(li))
    if len(intersection_set) == 1:
        return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: Edge case, but by your definition the first example should be invalid as both 1 and 2 are repeated in all (1) lists.

Answer (score 0):

Barring the edge cases (length of list = 1 and 0), you can verify two constraints are met:

1. Every list has an item in common (check first two lists for a common element, then check every subsequent list for this item)
2. The total number of unique items in all lists = n + 1, where n is the number of lists.

```
def validate(my_list):
     # edge cases
     if len(my_list) == 0:
        return False
     if len(my_list) == 1:
        if my_list[0][0] == my_list[0][1]: return False
        else: return True

     # get common element among first two lists
     if my_list[0][0] in my_list[1]:
         common = my_list[0][0]
     elif my_list[0][1] in my_list[1]:
         common = my_list[0][1]
     else: # no common element
          return False

     # verify every list has common element
     all_elements = []
     for sub_list in my_list:
        all_elements += sub_list
        if common not in sub_list:
            return False
 
     # verify correct # of unique elements
     unique = list(set(all_elements))
     if len(unique) != len(my_list) + 1: 
         return False
     
     return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools to flatten the initial list. Then Evaluate the count of each element. Now, check if the length of your list is in the count_dict or not. The 2nd part in the if condition(return statement) will check if all other values are unique or not.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
my_list =  [ [6, 2], [3, 6], [6, 2]]
def validate_list(my_list):
    flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*my_list))
    count_dict = Counter(flat_list).values()
    return len(my_list) in count_dict and len(count_dict) == len(my_list)+1

validate_list(my_list)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the correct solution. Each sub_list must share one common element, and the remaining elements must all be unique.

Comment: @DerekG Thanks : ) I've updated my answer. I Hope, I've not missed anything this time.